# How to check if SSH connection was established with AWS instance

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to connect to the Amazon EC2 instance via SSH using `boto`. I know that ssh connection can be established after some time after instance was created. So my questions are:

- Can I somehow check if SSH is up on the instance? (if so, how?)
- Or how can I check for the output of `boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance()`? I mean for example if the output prints out `Could not establish SSH connection`, than try again.

That's what I tried so far, but have no luck:

```
if instance.state == 'running':
    retry = True
    while retry:
        try:
            print 'Connecting to ssh'
            key_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh'), 'secret_key.pem')
            cmd = boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                                               key_path,
                                                               user_name='ec2-user')

            print instance.update()
            if cmd:
                retry = False
        except:
            print 'Going to sleep'
            time.sleep(10)

SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds
SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds
SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds
SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds
SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds
Could not establish SSH connection
```

And of course everything is working properly, because I can launch the same code after some time and will get a connection, and will be able to use `cmd.shell()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message "SSH Connection refused, will retry in 5 seconds" is coming from boto: http://code.google.com/p/boto/source/browse/trunk/boto/manage/cmdshell.py

Initially, 'running' just implicates that the instance has started booting. As long as `sshd` is not up, connections to port 22 are refused. Hence, what you observe is absolutely to be expected if `sshd` does not come up within the first 25 seconds of 'running' state.

Since it is not predictable when `sshd` comes up exactly and in case you do not want to waste time by just defining a constant long waiting period, you could implement your own polling code that in e.g. 1 to 5 second intervals checks if port 22 is reachable. Only if it is invoke `boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance()`.

A simple way to test if a certain TCP port of a certain host is reachable is via the `socket` module:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('hostname', 22))
    print "Port 22 reachable"
except socket.error as e:
    print "Error on connect: %s" % e
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 parts, one to check if the instance is running, then another one to check  if the instance is reachable

```
# Get instance status till it is running
status_output=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $instance_id)
instance_status=$(jq -n "$status_output" | jq .InstanceStatuses[0] | jq .InstanceState.Name)
echo $instance_status
while [ ${instance_status:1:-1} != running ]
do
    status_output=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $instance_id)
    instance_status=$(jq -n "$status_output" | jq .InstanceStatuses[0] | jq .InstanceState.Name)
    echo $instance_status
done

# Get instance reachability till it is ready 
status_output=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $instance_id)
instance_reachability=$(jq -n "$status_output" | jq .InstanceStatuses[0] | jq .InstanceStatus.Status)
echo $instance_reachability
while [ ${instance_reachability:1:-1} != ok ]
do
    status_output=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $instance_id)
    instance_reachability=$(jq -n "$status_output" | jq .InstanceStatuses[0] | jq .InstanceStatus.Status)
    echo $instance_reachability
done
```